# how to use image loader with $.get

Tags: jquery

how to use image loader with $.get 
when im doing ajax calls with $.get sometimes it takes
a few seconds for the effect to take place.
how can i put a loader so that the user knows to wait
until the data is loaded?

thanks

edit:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'ajax.php',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: 'shipping=' + sval,
    onBeforeSend: function()
    {
        $("table#cart tbody tr#line_top td ul#total li#shipping span").html("<img src='images/spinner.gif'>");
    },

    complete: function()
    {

    },

    success: function(out)
    {
        getShippingPrice = out.shippingPrice;
        getTotalPrice = out.cartTotal;
        $("table#cart tbody tr#line_top td ul#total li#shipping span").html(getShippingPrice);
        $("table#cart tbody tr#line_top td ul#total li#total span").html(getTotalPrice);
    }
});
```

edit2:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var getShippingPrice;
var getTotalPrice;

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".shipmethod").change(function() {
        sVal = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "ajax.php",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            data: "shipping=" + sVal,

            beforeSend: function()
            {
                $('.ajaxSpinner').show();
            },

            complete: function()
            {
                $('.ajaxSpinner').hide();
            },

            success: function(out)
            {
                getShippingPrice = out.shippingPrice;
                getTotalPrice = out.cartTotal;
                $("table#cart tbody tr#line_top td ul#total li#shipping span").html(getShippingPrice);
                $("table#cart tbody tr#line_top td ul#total li#total span").html(getTotalPrice);
            }
        });
    });
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have two possibilities.

Either use the full [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) method which provides you more power:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/foo.cgi',
    type: 'GET',
    beforeSend: function() {
        // TODO: show your spinner
        $('#ajaxSpinner').show();
    },
    complete: function() {
        // TODO: hide your spinner
        $('#ajaxSpinner').hide();
    },
    success: function(result) {
        // TODO: handle the results
    }
});
```

or use the [`$.ajaxSetup()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxsetup/) method to provide global setup hooks for all ajax requests:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function() {
        // TODO: show your spinner
        $('#ajaxSpinner').show();
    },
    complete: function() {
        // TODO: hide your spinner
        $('#ajaxSpinner').hide();
    }
});
```

and then do your [`$.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) as usual:

```
$.get('/foo.cgi', function(result) {
    // TODO: handle the results
});
```

Comment: @Sarmen B., you are using an event called `onBeforeSend` whereas it should be `beforeSend`. Please look at my sample code more carefully.

Comment: thanks i got it to work now, problem is though the first time i make the selection it works, the second time  i make the selection the loader doesn't show up. how can i make it show up each time the  selection is changed?

Comment: @Sarmen B., what selection are you talking about? In the success callback you seem to be replacing some DOM elements. Are you sure that you are not replacing the element that you have bound the .change event handler to? In this case you might need to use the [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) method to attach the event handler because when you replace the DOM element all handlers you might have attached to it will be erased.

Comment: if you look at my code the ajax is called based on a form selection. $(".shipmethod").change(function()    (look in edit2)

Comment: @Sarmen B., are you replacing the `.shipmethod` DOM element in the AJAX success callback?

Comment: this is the portion that the effect is being done to: <li id="shipping">Shipping: $<span><img src="images/loader.gif" class="ajaxSpinner"></span></li> the image portion is being shown on beforeSend and hidden on completed. the data coming back from ajax.php is being displayed in between the span elements.

Comment: and it looks like the image tag is being removed all together. everythign is being done in the span element